# Local and global variables in loops

Tags: javascript

I know basics about local and global variables, but could anybody explain difference between these two examples of code?

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.classname');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    // do something
}
```

and

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.classname');
for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {                 // <-- removed "var" before "i = 0"
    // do something
}
```

Comment: well technically `i` is global in the first code if it is not run inside a block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `var` keyword, there is no "block" scope, so declarations are either "function" scoped or "global". The fact that you declare a variable in a loop or in a true/false branch of an `if` statement does not create a variable scoped to just that block of code. This is quite different than in most compiled languages.

ECMAScript 2016 (a.k.a. ES6) introduces "block" scope with the `let` keyword.

So, if you omit the `var` keyword and just create a new variable in a function, that variable becomes global because the JS runtime doesn't know where you wanted it scoped to.

Here's some examples:

```js
// Outside of functions, the var keyword creates global variables
var g = "global";

function foo(){
  // Inside of functions, the var keyword creates "local" or function scoped variables
  var l = "local";
  
  // But, omitting the "var" keyword, whereever you do it, creates a global
  oops = "global";
  
  // But, creating a function scoped variable of the same name as a variable in a higher
  // scope, just hides the one from the higer scope as long as the code runs in the smaller
  // scope:
  var g = "local";

  // Other than global and function, the var keyword does not create "block" scope:
  if(true){
    var x = "surprise!";
  }
  
  // Now, we'll see what we get when we are in the local scope:
  console.log(g);     // "local", not "global" because smaller scope prevails 
  console.log(l);     // "local";
  console.log(oops);  // "global"
  console.log(x);     // "surprise!" because x has function scope, not block

}

foo();

  // Now, we'll see what is available back in the global scope:
  console.log(g);         // "global" because now we are in the global scope
  console.log(typeof l);  // It's an error to try to access directly, type is undefined
  console.log(oops);      // "global" because we omitted var and it became global
  console.log(typeof x);  // It's an error to try to access directly, type is undefined
```

Comment: OT, did you by any chance formerly work for an MSMQ wizard named Klaus?